# Centripetal Acceleration

Tags: physics

Here is my question:

> You are whirling a ball attached to a string such that you describe a
>   circle of radius $75$ cm, at a velocity of $1.50$ m/s. What is the
>   acceleration of the ball?

Could you show an equation to solve it?

My idea:

$$F_{\text{centripetal}} = \frac {v^2}{r}m$$

Regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$F=ma=\frac{mv^2}{r}$$
$$a=\frac{v^2}{r}$$

Comment: Thanks, I solved the problem from your equation.

Answer (score 0):

The centripetal acceleration is give by

$$a=\frac{v^2}{r}$$

Comment: @Denayer I don't understand why you need to derive the formula for centripetal acceleration, which is more fundamental, from the formula of centripetal force, which is in fact a result of the former!